# How can I make text wrap to scrollWidth rather than clientWidth?

Tags: html, css

NOTE: Despite the title, this question contains no JavaScript, I'm just using those terms to illustrate the problem.

I have a div of fixed width, and sometimes the content within it is too wide, so I have set it to `overflow: auto`, and that does work properly. However, if the div contains both text and an image, one that is too large to fit without overflowing, the text still wraps to the width of the visible portion of the div (`clientWidth`), rather than to its full extent (`scrollWidth`). This seems very ugly to me, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Simply turning off text wrapping is not a good solution either, because then the text will stretch the div far more than necessary if it is wider than the image.

[Example](http://codepen.io/AlphaModder/pen/ZpQBao)

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question.

This is the only workaround I could find so far that uses cross browser css.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKyGBr

```
.outer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer > div {
  display:table;
}

.outer > div > * {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border: 5px outset red;  
  display:block;
  margin:0;
}
```

## Flexbox solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrWVJY

```
.outer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.outer > div > * {
  display:block;
  border: 5px outset red;
  margin:0;
}
```

## Min-Content solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkPLdR

```
.outer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer > div {
  width:min-content;
  width:-moz-min-content;
}

.outer > div > * {
  border: 5px outset red;  
  display:block;
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: good solution- with flexbox you won't get the scroll unless you apply width to the image rather than `outer`

Comment: flexbox solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrWVJY i think it's impossible without using a wrapper element